# ZipOutputStream.closeEntry() hangs (java/jersey)

Tags: java, jersey, zipoutputstream

I'm trying to post an InputStream to a RESTful service. For normal files, this is fine.

In another place I'm trying to write a number of files to a piped zip stream on the fly. To do this I have a class that extends `InputStream` and when `read()` is called it writes the next file to the pipe. When the first file has been written I call `ZipOutputStream.closeEntry()` but it hangs. Why??

When I test this class in a unit test it works fine. When I try to post this object it hangs. The debugger is telling me its waiting for lock on `SocketWrapper`.

Note, I also tried setting media type to `application/octet-stream`. Also, the RESTful method is never called.

The stream class...

```
static class MultiStreamZipInputStream extends InputStream {

    private final Iterator<InputStream> streams;
    private final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream;
    private InputStream currentStream;
    private int counter = 0;

    public MultiStreamZipInputStream(List<InputStream> streamList) {

        streams = streamList.iterator();
        currentStream = streams.next();

        try {
            PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
            inputStream = new PipedInputStream(out);

            zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(out);
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(String.valueOf(counter++)); // Use counter for random name
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read()
        throws IOException {

        if (inputStream.available() != 0)
            return inputStream.read();

        if (currentStream == null)
            return -1;

        int bytesRead = currentStream.read(buffer);
        if (bytesRead >= 0) {

            zipOutputStream.write(buffer,  0,  bytesRead);
            zipOutputStream.flush();

        } else  {

            currentStream.close();
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();

            if (!streams.hasNext()) {
                currentStream = null;
                return -1;
            }

            currentStream = streams.next();
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(String.valueOf(counter++)));
        }

        return read();
    }
}
```

The posting code...

```
        MultiStreamZipInputStream myStream = ...

        Client client = Client.create();
        Builder webResource = client.resource("some URL").type("application/x-zip-compressed");
        webResource.post(ClientResponse.class, myStream);
```

The REST method on the other end...

```
@POST
@Path("/somemethod")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes({"application/x-zip-compressed"})
public Response someMethod(InputStream data) {...
```

Comment: Looks like it might be because the pipe write is blocked until a pipe read is performed. So, need to know how to get past this so the service can start reading.